# php while loop invoked remotely by cURL fails

Tags: php, curl

Long-time user, first-time poster, thanks for your patience!

This php code when invoked remotely through `cURL` fails unless I comment out the while loop, which of course defeats the code's purpose of reading through a file.  `fgets` is the right file reading tool for me, since the file contains text lines ending in a newline.

(I've created a slightly-awkward construction using `$readWorks` to help combine the while and if clauses and enable the code to work when the while loop is commented out.)

```
<?php
define( "IPDIRFILE", "path/to/ipfile.csv" ); // Lookup in standard file location as with local lookups
$readWorks = true;
$ipLookup = fopen( IPDIRFILE, "r" );
if ($ipLookup) {
//  while ( $readWorks ) { // Uncomment this loop to produce failure
    if (($ipline = fgets( $ipLookup )) !== false) {
        echo "Got the line with fgets: " . $ipline . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Can't fgets the line<br>";
        $readWorks = false;
    }
}
//} // Ending brace

fclose( $ipLookup );

?>
```

Here's the calling php code:

```
<?php
$varString = null;

$pgtCon = curl_init( 'http://domain/path/to/ipfinder.php' );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

// The content immediately below merely provides something to POST
$ipGeolocRequest = array();
// IP addresses pushed to $ipGeolocRequest

foreach ( $ipGeolocRequest as $ipIdx => $ipVal ) { // construct POST data
    $varString .= $ipIdx . "=" . $ipVal . "&";
}
$varString = substr($varString, 0, -1); // remove trailing ampersand

if (curl_setopt( $pgtCon, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $varString )) {
    $geoData = curl_exec( $pgtCon );
} else {
    echo "Option set failed<br>";
}
curl_close( $pgtCon );

unset( $varString );

echo $geoData . "<br>";

?>
```

Per other posts I've ensured the POST string is unset after the `cURL` call.  The top, remotely-invoked code works perfectly with or without the while loop when invoked locally through the browser address bar.  This indicates, I think, that the file opens and reads correctly, and the script is otherwise functional.

I'm brand-new to `cURL`, so I'm sure I'm missing something! (It also smells to me like those times when you miss something glaringly obvious ;-)

Why would this `cURL` invocation cause a php while loop to fail?

Comment: Is `$readWorks` defined before the while loop? Because I can't see it.

Comment: Yes, it's missing here.  I checked after adding it before the while loop in my test environment, and the loop still fails.  Now I'll try to edit my original post...thanks for the catch.

Comment: No problem, but that's all I noticed, I hope you'll get the answer needed!

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use `fgets()` on CSV files, it's better to use `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: Also, `$varString = http_build_query($ipGeolocRequest);` ... in any case, what do you mean by "while loop fails"?

Comment: Thanks, Jack--two great recommendations, I'll use them both.

Comment: I see that newline when typing a comment posts the comment...to continue, the symptom of while loop failing is that I see an empty browser window, no characters returned to the calling php program when I execute it in that browser window.  If I comment out the while loop, I receive the file data I expect.  This blank window has been indicative of a php error in the past, but I'm not sure how to diagnose it further.  There's no error_log file in the remote directory, and I don't have access to other server logs that I know of.

Comment: put this line at the very beginning of your script to have more error messages, but take it away when you go to production: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Ah, I knew of that, and didn't think of it.  Neural preoccupation.  I'm finding an out-of-memory error that could easily be the cause.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the help.  Once I had all the error messages and the memory usage issue was resolved, I was able to work through the many issues and get things working error-free.  I'll improve my process to better make use of basic troubleshooting.  If there's anything I need to do to close out this issue, since there are no answers to check, let me know.